# how to use axios on nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

hello i am trying fetch data from my backend but its look like not working also can't debug whats happening on load

i did try something like this

```
import axios from 'axios/dist/axios';

axios.get('http://api.chillwisper.tk/api/videos')
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
  this.videos = response.data.data
})
```

nothing happen no console logs nothing 
i also tried this

```
fetch("http://api.chillwisper.tk/api/videos")
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log('this is test shit')
                this.videos = response.data.data
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e.response)
            });
```

still not work how can do this i am new in nativescript but i know vue

Comment: Your API is http not https. Unsecured connection is not allowed by default in iOS and Android (Pie - v9 and above). Did you do all the setup?

Comment: ohhh okay let me test on https thanks